# How to make a JPanel use the scrollbars to fit in large J components?

Tags: java, swing

I have this problem where the JPanel (contentPane) re-sizes (testLabel) GUI components to be really small whenever they are too big to fit in the panel. I have added scrollbars to the JPanel but the components still re-size instead of using the scrollbars. Here is my class where I use the JPanel with scrollbars.

```
package marsPackage;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DashTab{

    private JLabel testLabel; //test label
    private JLabel testLabel2;
    private JLabel testLabel3;
    private JLabel testLabel4;
    private JPanel dashPanel; //Panel that holds the JTabbedPane tab
    private JPanel contentPane; // Panel that holds all GUI components
    private JScrollPane scrollPane; // Scrollpane used on contentPane

    /*
     * Constructor
     * All of your GUI components should be added to
     * contentPane using the gridBagLayout.
     */

    public DashTab(){
    //Creating the dashpanel that holds everything
    dashPanel = new JPanel();
    dashPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    //Creating the contentPane that holds all GUI components and
    //uses vertical/horizontal sidebards as needed
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    //Giving the contentPane the GridBagLayout
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();
    contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(857, 725));

    //Adding scrollPane to Content Pane and adding those two to dashPanel
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(contentPane);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    dashPanel.add(scrollPane);

    /*
     * You may begin adding your GUI components from this point forward.
     * Remember to only use GridBagLayout with GridBagConstraints using the
     * g variable.
     */

    testLabel = new JLabel("Testing Here 1");
    testLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    testLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, Color.gray));
    g.gridx = 0;
    g.gridy = 0;
    contentPane.add(testLabel, g);

    testLabel2 = new JLabel("Testing Here 2");
    testLabel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 200));
    testLabel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, Color.gray));
    g.gridx = 1;
    g.gridy = 0;
    contentPane.add(testLabel2, g);

    testLabel3 = new JLabel("Testing Here 3");
    testLabel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200)); 
    testLabel3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, Color.gray));
    g.gridx = 1;
    g.gridy = 1;
    contentPane.add(testLabel3, g);

    testLabel4 = new JLabel("Testing Here 4");
    testLabel4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200)); 
    testLabel4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, Color.gray));
    g.gridx = 2;
    g.gridy = 2;
    contentPane.add(testLabel4, g);
    }

    /**
     * The getDashTab method returns a DashTab object.
     * @return a DashTab panel object.
     */

    public JPanel getDashTab(){
            return dashPanel;
    }
}
```

This is how the above code looks like:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/lBSTfrt.jpg]

Whenever I remove `contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(857, 725));` the panel just stretches out and complete ignores the scrollbars making it look like:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/sMusbTm.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(857, 725));

Don't use the setPreferredSize() method to set the size. That is the job of the layout manager, in this case, the GridBagLayout to determine the size of the panel.

Scrollbars will appear automatically when the preferred size of the panel is greater than the size of the scrollpane.

> GUI components to be really small whenever they are too big to fit in the panel.

The GridBagLayout will try to respect the preferred size of the component. If the preferred size is greater than the size of the panel, then the components "minimum size" will be used. In the case of a JLabel, the minimum size is the space needed to entirely display the text.

Once again, don't try to use the setPreferedSize() method.

Comment: Thank you!
I removed: `contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(857, 725));` then added: `scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(857, 725));` and the result is just what I wanted: http://i.imgur.com/KpW2A4G.jpg

Comment: Don't use setPreferredSize() on the scrollpane either. The space available will automatically be calculated based on the size of the size of the largest tab added to the tabbed pane. If you use layout managers properly on all the tabs there is no need to manually set the preferred size.